# Visual Basic Listbox ItemsOfType

Tags: vb.net

I need to find max, average and range of a list of numbers entered in my `ListBox`. Numbers are being entered using a textbox area. I am trying to use this to get the max value of the `ListBox` but it's not working. Any idea why?

```
Dim listGradeHighest As Double = listGrade.Items.OfType(Of Integer).Max
resHighest.Text = listGradeHighest
```

It says: "Invalid Operation Exception was Unhandled".

Comment: What platform?  WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, etc?

Comment: [Please go through this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dd87444a-5076-42e0-a814-5157e26ade47/min-or-max-value-of-listbox?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: To be honest, SO has an answer for each of your separate components.

Answer (score 0):

try setting listGrade.Items.OfType(Of Integer) to listGrade.Items.OfType(Of Double), though i'm not too familiar with "oftype" but it might not like that you are trying to put an integer into a variable declared as a double

Answer (score 0):

Use linq

MAX

```
...Items.OrderByDescending(...).First
```

AVG

```
...Items.Average()
```

Range

```
...Items.Where(Function(i) i >= x andalso i <= y)
```

I didn't test if Linq is applicable to listBox items but if it is not you can make listbox get datasource from `List(of Integer)` and then use `DataSource` property to retrieve it. You will need to add your new items to that list instead of `Items.Add`

[This is good site](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq)